# getting error while connecting mongodb to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, web

I am getting error while trying to connect Mongodb and Nodejs on local server please any one help me with this problem

my JavaScript code

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

//provide the function sto connect to database
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const connectionURL = "mongodb://120.0.0.1:2701"
const databaseName = "task-manager"

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL,{useNewUrlParser:true},(error,client)=>{
if(error){
    return console.log(error)
}

console.log("connected to database")
})
```

[here is the screenshot of error which I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvH2z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says "connection time out", what means either your server is very slow or there is no mongoDB at the specified ip%port. If I assume that correctly that your mongoDB is running on localhost, that you have an typo in your `connectionURL`.You set it to **120**.0.0.1. It should probably be **127**.0.0.1.

`const connectionURL = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:2701"` or `const connectionURL = "mongodb://localhost:2701"`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this code:

```
const connectionURL = “mongodb://120.0.0.1:27017”;
```

And add `useUnifiedTopology:true` with `useNewUrlParser:true`